# How to make list including certain multi-bit letters by using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, readline

I am trying to list up certain words by using Python.

Here's the text file(input file): (the 'random_text' are random texts that exist in text file)

```
random_text

reg A1_M0;
reg A1_M1;
reg A1_M10;
reg A1_M11;
reg A1_M2;

reg [3:0] B1_M0;
reg [3:0] B1_M1;
reg [3:0] B1_M10;
reg [3:0] B1_M11;
reg [3:0] B1_M2;

random_text
```

I want to make below two lists by extracting the lines and spliting the data.

```
list1 = [A1_M0, A1_M1, A1_M10, A1_M11, A1_M2]

list2 = [B1_M0[3], B1_M0[2], B1_M0[1], B1_M0[0], B1_M1[3], B1_M1[2], ... , B1_M2[1], B1_M2[0]]
```

I thought about 3 steps:

1. Extract target data (by using '.findall') -> A1_M0, A1_M1, A1_M10, A1_M11, A1_M2, B1_M0[3:0], B1_M1[3:0], B1_M10[3:0], B1_M11[3:0], B1_M2[3:0]
2. In case of 4-bit-data, split all of those into 1-bit data.
3. Make these into 2 types of lists (list1, list2)

I've tried '.readlines' method, but It's hard for me to achieve. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

I made some assumptions that I hope were correct.

1. I group all bits together by their prefix, as that seems to be the commonality between the bits in `list1` and `list2`
2. The difference between your random text and meaningful data was the presence of the prefix "reg "
3. There are only 2 types of "reg " prefixed lines, and the difference is the presence of the "[" character, you can modify the conditions if there is a more nuanced definition than this.

```py
def get_reg_lines(f):
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "reg " in line:
            yield line.removeprefix('reg ').removesuffix(';\n')


def handle_single(d, line):
    k, _ = line.split("_", 1)
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(line)


def handle_multi(d, line):
    r, b = line.split(" ", 1)
    k, _ = b.split("_", 1)

    start, end = [int(v) for v in r[1:-1].split(":")]
    d.setdefault(k, []).extend([f'{b}[{i}]' for i in range(start, end - 1, -1)])


def main():
    d = {}
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in get_reg_lines(f):
            if "[" in line:
                handle_multi(d, line)
            else:
                handle_single(d, line)
    print(d)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I put them in a `dict` d keyed with the prefixes `A1` and `B1`. You can unpack these into whatever lists you need if that is your preferred way to interact with the data.

Also note: I used `removeprefix` and `removesuffix` which requires Python3.9 or newer, replace with slice notation for prior versions.

```py
yield line[4:-2]
```

*Code was tested on input.txt with the following contents:

```
random_text

reg A1_M0;
reg A1_M1;
reg A1_M10;
reg A1_M11;
reg A1_M2;

reg [3:0] B1_M0;
reg [3:0] B1_M1;
reg [3:0] B1_M10;
reg [3:0] B1_M11;
reg [3:0] B1_M2;

random_text
```